# Подскажите пожалуйста, где ошибка с импортами?

Tags: python-3.x, модули, пакеты

При запуске файла database.py выдает ошибку:

```
from config_data.config import Config, load_config
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config_data'
```

Код из database.py

```
import asyncio
from config_data.config import load_config, Config
import psycopg2


async def db_main():
    conn = await connect_db()
    with conn.cursor() as curs: #cоздать курсор
        curs.execute('SELECT * FROM users') #отправить запрос к БД
        all_strings = curs.fetchall() # вернуть все строки
        print(all_strings)


async def connect_db():
    config: Config = load_config('/.env')
    conn = psycopg2.connect(config.db.database, config.db.db_host,
                            config.db.db_user, config.db.db_password, config.db.db_port)

    return conn


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(db_main())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надо импортировать из пакета config_data и модуля config функцию load_config() и класс Config.

Пакет config_data и пакет database находятся на одном уровне в папке проекта.

Дописал в инит пакета config_data импорт, не помогло:

```
import config_data.config
```

Как починить это?

Comment: Для начала приложить код текстом

Comment: виноват! исправил

Comment: Может всё-таки `..config_data.config`? Или через название корневого пакета. Файл то ниже уровнем получается.

Comment: Попробуй: `from .config_data.config import load_config, Config`

Comment: На это ..config_data.config выдало ошибку что неизвестен родительский пакет (ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package), но ведь в данном случае родительский пакет - это config_data же да?

Comment: так пробовал - from .config_data.config import load_config, Config - так вообще не видит модуля и пакета

Comment: а файлы config.py и database.py на одном уровне но в разных пакетах

Comment: А если `from config_data import *` и попробуй database сделать выше уровнем

Comment: Может таки оформить верхний уровень тоже как пакет? Хотя вроде это и не требуется сейчас, но может поможет.

Comment: Т.е. из папки проекта сделать пакет?

Comment: Это конечно прозвучит глупо, но ты пробывал перезапустить виртуальное окружение?

Comment: да, конечно пробовал... )

Comment: Попробуй насильно впихнуть, через терминал `export PYTHONPATH=/полный/путь к корневому каталогу`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю два варианта, первый можно переместить пакет `config_data` в текущую директорию, тогда ничего не требуется просто `from config_data import config`
Второй вариант прописать путь к `config_data`

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'плоный или относительный путь/config_data')
from config_data import config
config.Config...
```

а еще можно посмотреть места где python просматривает,

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

и туда добавить если можно конечно.

Comment: А если использовать абсолютный импорт 
`from project_directory.config_data.config import Config, load_config` ну или насильно впихнуть путь к проекту в PYTHONPATH

Comment: Но  пакет config_data и так в папке проекта

Comment: project_directory - полный путь к корневому каталогу, извиняюсь, некорректно высказался, абсолютный импорт = полный путь